# How do I tell git to use fewer cores/threads when compressing?

Tags: git

I have a quad-core MacBook Pro (8 threads total) and once a week I am forced to wait about 5-7 minutes while the entire system becomes effectively unresponsive.  Multi-tasking is basically unavailable at this time.

git tells me it is using 8 threads.  How do I tell it to use less than that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Set the `pack.threads` configuration option to a value between 1 and 7, inclusive.

For example, if you wanted git to use 6 threads instead of 8:

```
git config --global pack.threads "6"
```

Alternatively, edit the .gitconfig:

```
[pack]
    threads = 6
```